# Using Elements in a List As Arguments in Racket/PLT Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

In a library I can not modify, there is a function that takes a list of values as one of its arguments.

For the sake of this question, we can just call it `fun`. I have a function that returns multiple arguments as a list, and was wondering how I can extract those values from the list and pass that into the function. For example, here is `fun`:

`(fun (list someval someval2 arg1 arg2 arg3 ... etc))`.

And my function that process data would return something akin to `(list arg1 arg2 arg3 ... etc)`. How could I pass the contents of the list that my function returns into fun, alongside `someval` and `someval2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`list*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=list*#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._list%2A%29%29):

```
(let ([someval (some-func ...)]
      [someval2 [some-func2 ...)]
      [args (my-func ...)])
  (fun (list* someval someval2 args)))
```

`list*` takes it's arguments and builds them into a list like `list` does, with the exception that if the last argument is a list, it uses that as the tail of the list, e.g. `(list* 1 2 '(3 4 5))` is `'(1 2 3 4 5)`. So once you calculate `someval`, `someval2`, and your list of arguments you want to pass to `fun` (I named the list `args` in the code above), you can build that into one list with `(list* someval someval2 args)`, then pass that list into `fun`.